# make: ***No rule to make target 'install'. when trying to install plib-1.8.5

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, cmake

First, i'd like to say i'm new to Ubuntu and Linux.
I got an error with `sudo make install` while following the instructions to install a plib-1.8.5.
(FYI 
1. It's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. There was no previous work done before.
2. I supposed to build a environment for TORCS simulator by gym_torcs.)

```
***No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.
```

I double-checked the directory where i executed, and from the results before this error, i could find the following messages. What am i missing?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your help in advance.

**SCRIPT USED**

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential libmicrohttpd-dev libssl-dev libhwloc-dev

git clone https://github.com/ugo-nama-kun/gym_torcs
cd gym_torcs

sudo apt-get install xautomation python3-pip
pip3 install gym
pip3 install numpy

cd vtorcs-RL-color

tar xzf plib-1.8.5.tar.gz 
cd plib-1.8.5 
./configure CFLAGS="-O2 -m64 -fPIC" CPPFLAGS="-O2 -fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -fPIC" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64"
```

**MESSAGE I GOT**

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
includedir changed to ${prefix}/include/plib libdir is ${exec_prefix}/lib
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for X... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... no
checking for glNewList in -lGL... no
checking for glNewList in -lMesaGL... no
configure: error: could not find working GL library
```

**NEXT SCRIPT USED**

```
sudo make install
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
***No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it seems that you do unnecessary things. Ubuntu repository have all *Portability Libraries* - [check search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libplib&searchon=names).

The *Portability Libraries: Development package* is available in all Ubuntu versions and named as `libplib-dev`.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install libplib-dev
```

and as the result you will get the same version 1.8.5.
After its installation you should follow your instruction further.

---

So you should always use search on https://packages.ubuntu.com before compiling stuff by your own.

---

**If you really need to compile library by yourself then read text below.**
As @AtomiX84 wrote you should ensure that `./configure` was finished without errors. It is comprehensive script which checks the systems for all needed build tools (compiler, linker and so on) and build-dependencies (headers and libraries).
APT can help you here - it has special command to get build-dependencies
`sudo apt-get build-dep libplib-dev` and after running of this command the `./configure` script will not fail.

Comment: I absolutely Agree with @N0rbert, anyway if you need to compile and install the package you have to run ./configure successfully first. but you output says it stops at: configure: error: "could not find working GL library" thath mean some prerequisites are missing.

Comment: @AtomiX84 thanks! I added information about getting build dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @AtomiX84 N0rbert, it was exactly what I haven't known. I also finished up all the instruction by what you comment. And also thanks to dependency things, now I understand the differences. Have an awesome day :)